# Author-year bibliography in bilingual text

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am writing a thesis where the introduction is in French while the chapters are in English. I would like to cite some papers in both the introduction and the chapters, with an appropriate preposition. For example, I would like to cite "paper1" by author1 & author2 published in year1, such that in the in introduction it yields "author1 et author2 (year)" and in the chapter "author1 and author2" (year), with both references corresponding to one entry in the reference page at the end (where it does not matter whether it is "et" or "and"). Is it possible?
I am using natbib and econ-aer.bst for the bibliography.

I have tried using:

```
\newcommand*{\andname}{et }
  \addto \captionsenglish {\renewcommand*{\andname}{and }}
  \addto \captionsfrench  {\renewcommand*{\andname}{et }} 

\newcommand*{\liaisonname}{et }
  \addto \captionsenglish {\renewcommand*{\liaisonname}{and }}
  \addto \captionsfrench  {\renewcommand*{\liaisonname}{et }}
```

and replacing "and" by `\andname` in `FUNCTION {bst.and}` & `FUNCTION {bst.ands}`, & "and" by `\liaisonname` in `FUNCTION {bst.cite.and}` & `FUNCTION {bst.cite.ands}` in econ-aer.bst. This enables to choose whether "et" or "and" is used, and to have a different preposition in the text and reference page, but it does not yield what I am looking for.

Here is a link to the bibliography style: http://shirotakeda.org/en/tex/econ-bst.html

And an example (with this example, the citation is "Author1 *and* Author2 (2003)" in both the introduction and the chapter, while I would like "Author1 *et* Author2 (2003)" in the introduction):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}

\newcommand*{\andname}{et }
  \addto \captionsenglish {\renewcommand*{\andname}{and }}
  \addto \captionsfrench  {\renewcommand*{\andname}{et }} 

\newcommand*{\liaisonname}{et }
  \addto \captionsenglish {\renewcommand*{\liaisonname}{and }}
  \addto \captionsfrench  {\renewcommand*{\liaisonname}{et }} 

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}
\chapter{Introduction générale}

Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \cite{author12003}.

\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter{A Fancy Title}

Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \cite{author12003}.

\selectlanguage{english}
\bibliographystyle{econ-aer}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

The entry in the biblio.bib is:

```
@Article{author12003,
  author={Author1 and Author2},
  title={{Title}},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2003,
  volume={71},
  number={5},
  pages={1491--1517},
  month={09}}
```

Comment: `biblatex` has extensive multi-language support. But you would have to switch from standard BibTeX to `biblatex` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`natbib` gets the author-year information by reading the optional argument of `\bibitem`/`\harvarditem` in the bibliography. But because the bibliography is usually included at the end of the document, that information comes too late to be useful, so LaTeX saved it in the `.aux` file, so it can be used from the beginning of the document.

The `.bbl` (bibliography) contains the line

```
\harvarditem[Author1 \andname{} Author2]{Author1 \andname{} Author2}{2003}{author12003}
```

and then that is written to the `.aux` as

```
\bibcite{author12003}{{1}{2003}{{Author1 and{} Author2}}{{Author1 and{} Author2}}}
```

Why does that happen? When LaTeX writes things to the `.aux` files it expands the text it writes, see [On the basics of writing to & reading from auxiliary files (.aux, .toc, etc.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115932/35864). At the point where the `.aux` is written `\andname` has the meaning `and`, so that ends up in the `.aux` file.

A simple solution is to make `\andname` robust. That makes sure that it is not expanded when it is written to the `.aux` file, so that the `.aux` contains

```
\bibcite{author12003}{{1}{2003}{{Author1 \andname{} Author2}}{{Author1 \andname{} Author2}}}
```

Together with the changes you already applied to the `.bst` file (rename the changed file to `econ-aer-ml.bst`)

```
--- econ-aer.bst    2018-07-20 15:27:43.069689500 +0200
+++ econ-aer-ml.bst 2018-07-20 14:53:32.187363500 +0200
@@ -228,7 +228,7 @@
 % String replaced with _ in "Mr. A _ Mr. B "
 %
 FUNCTION {bst.and}
-{ ", and " }
+{ " \andname{} " }
 % { " and " }    % (default)

 %%% String used to separate author names in references (more than two authors).
@@ -236,21 +236,21 @@
 % String replaced with _ in "Mr. A, Mr. B _ Mr. C"
 %
 FUNCTION {bst.ands}
-{ ", and " }    % (default)
+{ " \andname{} " }    % (default)

 %%% String used to separate author names in citation part.
 %
 % String replaced with _ in "Mr. A _ Mr. B "
 %
 FUNCTION {bst.cite.and}
-{ " and " }    % (default)
+{ " \andname{} " }    % (default)

 %%% String used to separate author names in citation part (more than two authors).
 %
 % String replaced with _ in "Mr. A, Mr. B _ Mr. C"
 %
 FUNCTION {bst.cite.ands}
-{ " and " }    % (default)
+{ " \andname{} " }    % (default)

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd*{\andname}{et}
  \addto \extrasenglish {\renewrobustcmd*{\andname}{and}}
  \addto \extrasfrench  {\renewrobustcmd*{\andname}{et}}

\newrobustcmd*{\liaisonname}{et}
  \addto \extrasenglish {\renewrobustcmd*{\liaisonname}{and}}
  \addto \extrasfrench  {\renewrobustcmd*{\liaisonname}{et}}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{author12003,
  author={Author1 and Author2},
  title={{Title}},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2003,
  volume={71},
  number={5},
  pages={1491--1517},
  month={09}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{french}
\chapter{Introduction générale}
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \cite{author12003}.

\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter{A Fancy Title}
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \cite{author12003}.

\selectlanguage{english}
\bibliographystyle{econ-aer-ml}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: "Author1 et Author2 (2003)"]

[image: "Author1 and Author2 (2003)"]

---

`biblatex` offers multilingual support out of the box. So if you don't have to use `natbib` and `econ-aer`, you may want to consider switching to `biblatex`. See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864).

```
\documentclass[french,british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

\selectlanguage{french}\cite{sigfridsson}

\selectlanguage{british}\cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]