# Latex Log File Customization

Tags: external-files, logging

I use TexMaker, pdflatex.
I have a tex file for which I am using the console to debug my functions and check to make sure my functions are working properly. 
However there is too much junk in the log file for the console to actually be of use.
I would like to be able to completely overwrite the log after my document has compiled. 
Either that, output at the end of the log file, or remove the statistics at the end of the log file.

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to write to a separate log file? See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115932/on-the-basics-of-writing-to-reading-from-auxiliary-files-aux-toc-etc, last part of the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is what I am essentially trying to avoid. Because I will have to reopen the file every time there are changes, which means constantly reopening the file every time.