# Don't work \immediate\write

Tags: output, immediate

I'm writing my own `.sty` file. It contains its own table of contents and commands like `\section{}`, but nothing works because the output to the file for the table of contents does not work correctly

Here's what the output should look like:

```
\hyperref[mysection1]{\bfseries  3\hskip 1em\relax Section\dotfill  \pageref  {mysection1}}
\hyperref[mysection2]{\bfseries  3\hskip 1em\relax Section\dotfill  \pageref  {mysection2}}
```

аnd here's what it looks like:

```
\hyperref  [mysection3]{\bfseries  3\hskip 1em\relax Section\dotfill  \pageref  {mysection3}}
\hyperref  [mysection3]{\bfseries  3\hskip 1em\relax Section\dotfill  \pageref  {mysection3}}
```

Here is the code from `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mysty}

\begin{document}
    \mytableofcontents
    
    \section{Section}
    
    \section{Section}
\end{document}
```

Here is the code from `mysty.sty` file:

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\newwrite\myoutput
\immediate\openout\myoutput=toc.tex

\newcounter{sections}
\setcounter{sections}{1}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
    
    \vspace{2ex}
    \label{mysection\the\value{sections}}%
    \noindent\textbf{\arabic{sections}.\quad #1}%
    \write\myoutput{\hyperref[mysection\the\value{sections}]{\bfseries\the\value{sections}\quad #1\dotfill\pageref{mysection\arabic{sections}}}}%
    \stepcounter{sections}
    
    \vspace{2ex}
}

\newcommand{\mytableofcontents}{%
    \newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
    \noindent\textbf{Table of Contents}
    
    \input{toc}
    
    \newpage
}

\endinput
```

Comment: You are not using \immediate\write as you claim in the title of your question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you add `\immediate` before `\write`, a lot of errors will come out

Comment: write expands its arguments so you need to protect expansion but still expand the things you need but you will not get correct page numbers with `\immediate\write`. But why are you not using any of the facilities latex offers for section commands and writing the table of contents data?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115933/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need to customize all of the section commands and the view of the table of contents

Comment: latex sectioning is highly customisable but this just removes all features. Apart from breaking the table of contents, you are losing all the control latex has over avoiding page breaks close to section headings or to the indentation of following paragraphs, and removing the ability to `\label` and `\ref` sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand why you want to do manually what the LaTeX kernel does better by itself.

Anyway, doing `\immediate\openout\myoutput` in the `.sty` file has the consequence that the `toc` file is cleared as soon as the file is loaded, so you will get ***nothing*** in the table of contents.

You must start writing it ***after*** the table of contents (as built in the previous run) has been typeset.

You also get no anchor if you do `\stepcounter{sections}`. You need `\refstepcounter{sections}` before `\label` (and to not initialize the counter to 1, of course).

Another obvious weakness of the code is that you're forced to have the table of contents at the beginning. With the standard `\tableofcontents` you can put it anywhere.

You also need to protect commands from expansion inside `\write`.

Here's a working version of your code. But you ***should not*** do it yourself: use the standard tools and customize them. For instance, as noted by David Carlisle, you may well get a section title at the bottom of a page, with the text in the following page.

Check for the differences.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
%\usepackage{mysty}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\newwrite\myoutput
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\myoutput}

\newcounter{sections}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
    \par\vspace{2ex}
    \refstepcounter{sections}\label{mysection\the\value{sections}}%
    \noindent\textbf{\arabic{sections}.\quad #1}%
    \immediate\write\myoutput{%
      \noindent
      \noexpand\hyperref[mysection\the\value{sections}]{%
        \noexpand\bfseries\the\value{sections}\noexpand\quad #1%
        \noexpand\dotfill\noexpand\pageref{mysection\arabic{sections}}%
      }%
      \noexpand\par
    }%
    \par\vspace{2ex}
}

\newcommand{\mytableofcontents}{%
    \newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
    \noindent\textbf{Table of Contents}\par
    \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.toc}{}%
    \newpage
    \immediate\openout\myoutput=\jobname.toc
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mytableofcontents
    
\section{Section}
    
\section{Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't understand how to customize standard tools at a low level, I learned how to do this for headers and footers and page markup, but I haven't found a solution for other tools yet

Comment: @AndrewD. For customizing section titles you can look at `titlesec`; for the table of contents, look at `titletoc` or `etoc`. Don't try these low level customization by hand.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `\immediate` before `\write`. The you can't be surprised that you have delayed `\write`.

Adding `\immediate` before `\write` without another changes yields to error, because the parameter of `\write` is immediately expanded. You want to expand only `\the\value{sections}`, nothing more.

Your line with `\write` in your `mysty.sty` should be:

```
    \immediate\write\myoutput
       {\string\hyperref[mysection\the\value{sections}]{\noexpand\bfseries\the\value{sections}\quad #1\string\dotfill\string\pageref{mysection\the\value{sections}}}}%
```

Comment: now there is another problem, the `\input` command inside the `\tableofcontents` command does not seem to work, and at the same time `\label` inside the `\section` command works somehow strangely: `\pageref` to mysection2 returns 2, and `\hyperref` to mysection2 when clicking on the text refers to the table of contents

Comment: You solved the least problem. Of course, the toc file will be cleared before it's read in, so nothing will appear in the table of contents.